# Can a website developer tell if I am using a Webbrowse control to navigate their website?

Tags: http, webbrowser-control, user-agent

Can a website developer tell if i'm using a Webbrowse control to navigate their website? And how can I make the Webbrowse control look like a web browser to the website?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: http://www.useragentstring.com/, which shows you what user agent strings are in use by known browsers and other web-clients.  You can send the user agent string of a known (other) browser to identify yourself as that brower to the server.

You'll also find this helpful, I think:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/08/extending-the-user-agent-string-problems-and-alternatives.aspx.  It's a Microsoft guy in charge of the IE user agent string.

Answer (score 0):

Change your User Agent to report a desktop browser.

Edit:

On the `WebBrowser.Navigate` method, you can pass a string with the UserAgent.

Comment: WebBrowser1.Navigate("website", "_self", Nothing, "User-Agent:") , i tried that and i still get blocked using the control

Comment: You'll have to actually give add something to the user-agent string.